# Converting character data to numeric for random forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I have the following dataframe containing passwords and their strength on a scale of 0-4:

```
> head(passwords_data)
          password score
1         kzde5577     2
2         kino3434     2
3        visi7k1yr     2
4         megzy123     2
5      lamborghin1     1
6 AVYq1lDE4MgAZfNt     4
```

I would like to build a password strength classification model with the Random Forest package in R. What is the best way to change the input (password column) to a numeric type?
In python i saw that tokenization and TfidfVectorizer are used.
How to deal with this in R to build the model correctly?

my code so far:

```
split <- sample.split(passwords_data$password, SplitRatio = 0.8)

train <- subset(passwords_data, split == "TRUE")
test <- subset(passwords_data, split == "FALSE")

rf <- randomForest(password~., data = train, ntree = 500) # here I'm getting error "Error in y - ymean : non-numeric argument to binary operator..."
```

Comment: Please add the existing code so that it's possible to give better advice and hints how to improve your approach.

Comment: Have you got a link to a python example?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/code/timmofeyy/machine-learning-password-weakness-prediction

Comment: I tried to change password column to `factor` but randomForest function returned an error.

Comment: Suggest you ask about this in a machine learning Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find tokenization, feature matrix and tf-idf methods from text mining and NLP packages ( [CRAN NLP task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) ). For example with `quanteda` you could chain `tokens() |> dfm() |> dfm_tfidf()` to get a feature matrix suitable for `randomForest()` . For comparable results, you should probably go through default values for both `sklearn` and `quanteda` methods and perhaps consider how defaults fit for this specific application, e.g. by default `dfm()` converts features to lowercase.

```r
library(quanteda)
library(randomForest)

passwords_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~password,     ~score,
  "kzde5577",         2,
  "kino3434",         2,
  "visi7k1yr",        2,
  "megzy123",         2,
  "lamborghin1",      1,
  "AVYq1lDE4MgAZfNt", 4,
  )

# tokenized to characters
pw_tokens <- tokens(passwords_data$password, "character")
pw_tokens |> as.list() |> str()
#> List of 6
#>  $ text1: chr [1:8] "k" "z" "d" "e" ...
#>  $ text2: chr [1:8] "k" "i" "n" "o" ...
#>  $ text3: chr [1:9] "v" "i" "s" "i" ...
#>  $ text4: chr [1:8] "m" "e" "g" "z" ...
#>  $ text5: chr [1:11] "l" "a" "m" "b" ...
#>  $ text6: chr [1:16] "A" "V" "Y" "q" ...
  
# document-feature matrix
pw_dfm <- dfm(pw_tokens) 
print(pw_dfm, max_nfeat = 30)
#> Document-feature matrix of: 6 documents, 26 features (65.38% sparse) and 0 docvars.
#>        features
#> docs    k z d e 5 7 i n o 3 4 v s 1 y r m g 2 l a b h q f t
#>   text1 1 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>   text2 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>   text3 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>   text4 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>   text5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
#>   text6 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 0 1 1 1

# tf-idf
pw_tfidf <-  dfm_tfidf(pw_dfm)

# first 15 tokens 
as.matrix(pw_tfidf)[,1:15] |> round(2)
#>        features
#> docs      k   z    d   e    5    7   i   n    o    3    4    v    s    1   y
#>   text1 0.3 0.3 0.48 0.3 1.56 0.95 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0
#>   text2 0.3 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.3 0.3 0.48 0.95 0.95 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.0
#>   text3 0.3 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.48 0.6 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.48 0.78 0.18 0.3
#>   text4 0.0 0.3 0.00 0.3 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.48 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.18 0.3
#>   text5 0.0 0.0 0.00 0.0 0.00 0.00 0.3 0.3 0.48 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.18 0.0
#>   text6 0.0 0.3 0.48 0.3 0.00 0.00 0.0 0.3 0.00 0.00 0.48 0.48 0.00 0.18 0.3

# random forest for regression
pw_rf <- randomForest(x = as.matrix(pw_tfidf), y = passwords_data$score)
passwords_data$rf_predict <- apply(pw_tfidf, 1, \(x) predict(pw_rf, x))
passwords_data
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   password         score rf_predict
#>   <chr>            <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 kzde5577             2       2.08
#> 2 kino3434             2       2.00
#> 3 visi7k1yr            2       1.95
#> 4 megzy123             2       2.00
#> 5 lamborghin1          1       1.76
#> 6 AVYq1lDE4MgAZfNt     4       3.20
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>